# Convert clustered primary key to non-clustered and use another column for the clustered index

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008, index, clustered-index

I have a large table with a primary key (GUID) that is also the clustered index. There is already a integer sequence based field. So I want to leave the GUID as the PK and make the integer column the clustered index.

I can't figure any way to do this except drop the original constraint and create new PK and and new clustered index. But this takes a long time and from what I gather, rebuilds the table twice, once to go from clustered index to heap, and then heap back to clustered index.

I can't do a table rebuild (create new, migrate data, swap names) since I can't have an outage.

Any ideas?

Version: SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Developer/Enterprise.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can perform this operation online, since you can't just move the clustered index from one column to another, and you can't use `DROP_EXISTING` to reduce the amount of work that has to be done.

However, you can avoid an outage, if you're willing to perform the work.

1. Create a new table with the new structure
2. Rename the original table, and create a view with the original name - the view will be  a union of old and new table - performance won't be fantastic but it won't be offline
3. Create INSTEAD OF triggers on the view to apply DML to old or new table

   - inserts should just go to new table
   - updates should try both
   - deletes should try both
4. Copy rows, in chunks, from the old table to the new table. Will need SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON and you should perform each "chunk" in its own transaction.
5. Once the old table contains no rows that don't exist in the new table, in a single transaction:

   - drop the old table
   - drop the view
   - rename the new table

Comment: Will this work if there are FKs referencing the table? (we can't reference a view and new inserts will not go into the original table. I guess a variation where inserting goes to both might work.)

Comment: @ypercube Yes, you could insert new rows into both tables and then as part of step 5 you change the FKs to point to the new table. Or you could just drop those constraints for the duration of this operation. Hopefully this is something that takes minutes/hours, not hours/days.

Comment: Aaron is right, there's no way to do this without some outage. You could minimize the outage by swapping schema, and [I think someone even blogged about it](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/04/t-sql-queries/schema-switch-a-roo-part-2)

Comment: Why can't he move the CI online "from one column to another" using DROP_EXISTING, ONLINE? Is there a rule preventing that?

Comment: @usr Yes, have you tried it? `DROP_EXISTING` is not an option for `ADD CONSTRAINT`, btw, so you can only replace a PK constraint with a unique clustered index. Down in the bowels it's the same thing, but semantics may be important. Anyway, trying this yields `Msg 1907 : Cannot recreate index 'pk_whatever'. The new index definition does not match the constraint being enforced by the existing index.`

Comment: True, can't use DROP_EXISTING for dropping a PK. Index DDL really is a mess in so many ways. Trivial syntax rules make certain useful operations impossible. The engine is well capable of doing this.